# How to use standard fields like crdate and cruser_id with TYPO3 and extbase?

Tags: model, typo3, extbase

I have the domain models Basket and Article. If I call the following I receive the articles in the basket.

```
$articlesInBasket = $basket->getArticles();
```

How can I use the TYPO3 standard attributes like crdate and cruser_id. It would be nice to use something like this:

```
$basket->getCrUser();
$basket->getCrDate();
```

Comment: Typo3 8.7.x you need to add the field to the column configuration in the model's TCA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, the table fields are named as `crdate`, and `cruser` so getters should be named `getCrdate` and get `getCruser`

Next in your model you need to add a field and a getter:

```
/** @var int */
protected $crdate;

/**
* Returns the crdate
*
* @return int
*/
public function getCrdate() {
    return $this->crdate;
}
```

(do the same with `cruser` field)

And finally in you `setup.txt` most probably you'll need to add a mappings for these fields:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    Tx_Someext_Domain_Model_Somemodel {
        mapping {
            columns.crdate.mapOnProperty = crdate
            columns.cruser.mapOnProperty = cruser    
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, don't forget to use proper names in the settings, and clear the cache after changes in the code

Comment: Thanks - crdate works. But I can't get the user behind cruser_id. Do you have an Example to map the cruser_id to a Domain Model?

Comment: you can use the mapping in ts to create a better variable name. Maybe you have to add a relation to the be_users table.

Comment: crdate is not a string, but a int(11) unsigned. Therefore it should rather be /** @var int  */.

Comment: I created a combination of your and webMans answer. The mapping was needed in my case which is why webMans solution didn't completely work out for me. Instead of an int one can use `\DateTime` as well. Works like a charm though!

Answer (score 17):

This works in TYPO3 8.7 and 9.5

model:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $crdate = null;


/**
 * Returns the creation date
 *
 * @return \DateTime $crdate
 */
public function getCrdate()
{
    return $this->crdate;
}
```

TCA -> add this in the colums;

```
'columns' => [
    'crdate' => [
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'passthrough',
        ],
    ],

    ...

]
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me with TYPO3 6.2.11

model:

```
/**
 * tstamp
 *
 * @var int
 */
protected $tstamp;


/**
 * @return int $tstamp
 */
public function getTstamp() {
    return $this->tstamp;
}
```

TS:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    STUBR\Stellen\Domain\Model\Institution {
        mapping {
            tableName = tx_stellen_domain_model_institution
            columns {
                tstamp.mapOnProperty = tstamp
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS Thanks https://github.com/castiron/cicbase