# TYPO3 set month from crdate

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

i would like to get the month of my etbase item. In the database there is the crdate. I would like to use this and only get the month. My value is  always empty.

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $month = '';

/**
 * Returns the month
 *
 * @return string $month
 */
public function getMonth()
{
    return $this->month;
}

/**
 * Sets the month
 *
 * @param string $month
 * @return void
 */
public function setMonth(string $month)
{
    $month = 'dsds';
    $this->month = $month;
}
```

In my TCA if added this:

```
'month' => [
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'passthrough',
    ],
],
```

How can i get the month of the item? I would like to group it in my fluid template.

EDIT:

Ive tried it with a ViewHelper

```
<?php
namespace Ext\XY\ViewHelpers;

/*                                                                        *
 * This script belongs to the FLOW3 package "Fluid".                      *
 *                                                                        *
 * It is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under    *
 * the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the *
 * Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your *
 * option) any later version.                                             *
 *                                                                        *
 * This script is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but     *
 * WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHAN-    *
 * TABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser       *
 * General Public License for more details.                               *
 *                                                                        *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public       *
 * License along with the script.                                         *
 * If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html                      *
 *                                                                        *
 * The TYPO3 project - inspiring people to share!                         *
 *                                                                        */
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContextInterface;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\Variables\VariableExtractor;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Traits\CompileWithRenderStatic;

/**
 * Grouped loop view helper for Datetime values.
 * Loops through the specified values
 *
 * = Examples =
 *
 * <code title="Simple">
 * // $items = array(
 * //   array('name' => 'apple', 'start' => DateTimeObject[2011-10-13 00:15:00]),
 * //   array('name' => 'orange', 'start' => DateTimeObject[2011-12-01 00:10:00]),
 * //   array('name' => 'banana', 'start' => DateTimeObject[2008-05-24 00:40:00])
 * // );
 * <a:groupedForDateTime each="{items}" as="itemsByYear" groupBy="start" format="Y" groupKey="year">
 *   {year -> f:format.date(format: 'Y')}
 *   <f:for each="{itemsByYear}" as="item">
 *     {item.name}
 *   </f:for>
 * </a:groupedForDateTime>
 * </code>
 *
 * Output:
 * 2011
 *   apple
 *   orange
 * 2010
 *   banana
 *
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html GNU Lesser General Public License, version 3 or later
 * @api
 */
class GroupedForDateTimeViewHelper extends AbstractViewHelper
{

    use CompileWithRenderStatic;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    protected $escapeOutput = false;

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function initializeArguments()
    {
        parent::initializeArguments();
        $this->registerArgument('each', 'array', 'The array or \SplObjectStorage to iterated over', true);
        $this->registerArgument('as', 'string', 'The name of the iteration variable', true);
        $this->registerArgument('groupBy', 'string', 'Group by this property', true);
        $this->registerArgument('format', 'string', 'The format for the datetime', false);
        $this->registerArgument('groupKey', 'string', 'The name of the variable to store the current group', false, 'groupKey');
        $this->registerArgument('dateTimeKey', 'string', 'dateTimeKey The name of the variable to store the current datetime', false);
    }

    /**
     * @param array $arguments
     * @param \Closure $renderChildrenClosure
     * @param RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function renderStatic(array $arguments, \Closure $renderChildrenClosure, RenderingContextInterface $renderingContext)
    {
        $each = $arguments['each'];
        $as = $arguments['as'];
        $groupBy = $arguments['groupBy'];
        $groupKey = $arguments['groupKey'];
        $format = $arguments['format'];
        $dateTimeKey = $arguments['dateTimeKey'];
        $output = '';
        if ($each === null) {
            return '';
        }
        if (is_object($each)) {
            if (!$each instanceof \Traversable) {
                throw new ViewHelper\Exception('GroupedForViewHelper only supports arrays and objects implementing \Traversable interface', 1253108907);
            }
            $each = iterator_to_array($each);
        }

        $groups = static::groupElements($each, $groupBy, $format);

        $templateVariableContainer = $renderingContext->getVariableProvider();
        foreach ($groups['values'] as $currentGroupIndex => $group) {
            $templateVariableContainer->add($groupKey, $groups['keys'][$currentGroupIndex]);
            $templateVariableContainer->add($as, $group);
            $output .= $renderChildrenClosure();
            $templateVariableContainer->remove($groupKey);
            $templateVariableContainer->remove($as);
        }
        return $output;
    }


    /**
     * Groups the given array by the specified groupBy property.
     *
     * @param array $elements The array / traversable object to be grouped
     * @param string $groupBy Group by this property
     * @param string $format The format for the datetime
     * @return array The grouped array in the form array('keys' => array('key1' => [key1value], 'key2' => [key2value], ...), 'values' => array('key1' => array([key1value] => [element1]), ...), ...)
     * @throws ViewHelper\Exception
     */
    protected static function groupElements(array $elements, $groupBy, $format)
    {
        $extractor = new VariableExtractor();
        $groups = ['keys' => [], 'values' => []];
        foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $currentGroupIndex = isset($value[$groupBy]) ? $value[$groupBy] : null;
            } elseif (is_object($value)) {
                $currentGroupIndex = $extractor->getByPath($value, $groupBy);
            } else {
                throw new ViewHelper\Exception('GroupedForViewHelper only supports multi-dimensional arrays and objects', 1253120365);
            }


            if (strpos($format, '%') !== false) {
                $formatedDatetime = strftime($format, $currentGroupIndex->format('U'));
            } else {
                $formatedDatetime = $currentGroupIndex->format($format);
            }
            $groups['dateTimeKeys'][$formatedDatetime] = $currentGroupIndex;

            if (strpos($format, '%') !== false) {
                $currentGroupIndex = strftime($format, $currentGroupIndex->format('U'));
            } else {
                $currentGroupIndex = $currentGroupIndex->format($format);
            }

            $currentGroupKeyValue = $currentGroupIndex;
            if ($currentGroupIndex instanceof \DateTime) {
                //$currentGroupIndex = $currentGroupIndex->format(\DateTime::RFC850);
                $formatedDatetime = $currentGroupIndex->format($format);
                $groups['dateTimeKeys'][$formatedDatetime] = $currentGroupIndex;
            } elseif (is_object($currentGroupIndex)) {
                $currentGroupIndex = spl_object_hash($currentGroupIndex);
            }
            $groups['keys'][$currentGroupIndex] = $currentGroupKeyValue;
            $groups['values'][$currentGroupIndex][$key] = $value;
        }
        return $groups;
    }
}
```

and this in the fluid template

```
<a:groupedForDateTime each="{items}" as="itemsByYear" groupBy="start" format="Y" groupKey="year">
        <a:groupedForDateTime each="{itemsByYear}" as="itemsByMonth" groupBy="start" format="m" dateTimeKey="month">
            <div class="yearMonth clearfix">
                <div class="timeframe" data-behavior="FixTimeframe">
                    {month -> f:format.date(format: 'F Y')}
                </div>
                <f:for each="{itemsByMonth}" as="item">
                    <div class="item">
                        <p class="startEnd">
                            <a:format.duration start="{item.start}" end="{item.end}"/>
                        </p>
                        <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                        <div class="text">
                            <f:format.html>{item.bodyText}</f:format.html>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </f:for>
            </div>
        </a:groupedForDateTime>
    </a:groupedForDateTime>
```

then ill get this error:

```
Fluid parse error in template partial_Archive/ListItems_6877ade17ed77be0a2f8660fe2717844ab3400c3, line 25 at character 30. Error: The ViewHelper "<a:format.duration>" could not be resolved. Based on your spelling, the system would load the class "Ext\XY\ViewHelpers\Format\DurationViewHelper", however this class does not exist. (error code 1407060572). Template source chunk: <a:format.duration start="{item.start}" end="{item.end}"/>
```

Comment: i edited my answer to give you the solution for the second problem

Answer (score 1):

Your value is empty because TYPO3 does not know where to map it. If you do not have a month column on your table, TYPO3 wont even try to find something. So if you want to use the `$month` as a placeholder for the `crdate` you can do it like this in TYPO3 10 and above. I have tested this on TYPO3 11 and it works for TYPO3 10 as well.

**Your Domain Model**

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected string $month = '';

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getMonth(): string
{
    return date('F', (int)$this->month);
}

/**
 * @param string $month
 */
public function setMonth(string $month): void
{
    $this->month = $month;
}
```

Now TYPO3 needs the configuration of the field and this can be achieved on your TCA. You do not need to add it on your `types` or anywhere else. You just need the configuration. So in your TCA:

```
'crdate' => [
     'config' => [
         'type' => 'input',
         'size' => 10,
         'max' => 255,
     ],
],
```

Now TYPO3 know how can it display it BUT it doesn't know the source of the information. So you need to tell TYPO3 where the information is coming from. This can be achieved in your `Classes.php`. So under `your_extension/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php` you need to return the following:

```
return [
   \YourVendor\YourExtension\Domain\Model\YourModel::class => [
    'properties' => [
      'month' => [
        'fieldName' => 'crdate'
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

---

**EDIT**

While i was writing this answer, you ve changed the whole concept. Regarding your new Problem, you need to declare the ViewHelper either in your Fluid or globally on your ext_localconf.php

**Fluid**
At the very TOP of your Fluid you can add the namespace with one of the two ways.

First way:

```
{namespace blog=Ext\XY\ViewHelpers}
```

Second way:

```
<html
xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
xmlns:blog="http://typo3.org/ns/Ext/XY/ViewHelpers"
data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
```

You can declare it globally in your `ext_localconf.php` as well with the following lines:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['fluid']['namespaces']['blog'] = [
    'Ext\XY\ViewHelpers',
];
```

According to your ViewHelper, you ViewHelper class should be under `your_extension/Classes/ViewHelpers/Format/DurationViewHelper`. That is the reason why you get the error

> Fluid parse error in template partial_Archive/ListItems_6877ade17ed77be0a2f8660fe2717844ab3400c3, line 25 at character 30. Error: The ViewHelper "<a:format.duration>" could not be resolved. Based on your spelling, the system would load the class "Ext\XY\ViewHelpers\Format\DurationViewHelper", however this class does not exist. (error code 1407060572). Template source chunk: <a:format.duration start="{item.start}" end="{item.end}"/>

If this doesn't resolve your Problem, maybe you should just build the autoload information again. TYPO3 might not be aware of the new class yet

Comment: Thank you! Can i group elements in fluid with the month? this shoul be no problem withoud the ViewHelper and just the month right?

Comment: But now the crdate is empty. i need both values

Comment: then you can follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71733575/typo3-get-the-user-from-cruser-id-field?noredirect=1#comment126771758_71733575 and then get the month value directly from the crdate getter. You can remove the TCA and mapping and in your getMonth() function, you can do the following:  return date('F', (int)$this->getCrdate());

Comment: Thank you. So i dont need to change anything in the classes.php? If i just add the mothods in my model than the month is always empty

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the same information twice. There is another thread "[How to use standard fields like crdate and cruser_id with TYPO3 and extbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50663006/6783328)" discussing the use of standard fields.

If you only want to use the month of crdate in FLUID, you can use ViewHelpers in the template to format the data according to your needs. In this case, [`format.data`](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/main/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Format/Date.html) would help.

Comment: I have the crdate and the tstamp but woul like to add the month and the year seperate to work with it like this ```groupBy="month"``` in the FLUID-Template. So it doesnt help me to format the crdate.

Comment: Oh... That's indeed impossible via standard ViewHelpers :-/ Maybe an own VH can help: https://gist.github.com/daKmoR/1287203/f2c3a645951b808f7e4f25a667a959b6f11a2cc0

Comment: Ive triet this one but it seems like this one is deprecated

Comment: You have ssen the "I updated it for TYPO3 10.4" comment? https://gist.github.com/daKmoR/1287203?permalink_comment_id=3439610#gistcomment-3439610 And, yes, maybe it's not an out-of-the-box solution.

Comment: Ive added my code and the error above

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date/time in a FLUID variable you can use the `f:format` viewhelper to access each value individually, even in different formats.

If you want one value more often and want to avoid the repetition of the viewhelper store the value in a new FLUID variable.

```html
<f:variable name="day"       value="{mydate->f:format.date(format:'d')}" />
<f:variable name="weekday"   value="{mydate->f:format.date(format:'%A')}" />
<f:variable name="month"     value="{mydate->f:format.date(format:'m')}" />
<f:variable name="monthname" value="{mydate->f:format.date(format:'%B')}" />
<f:variable name="year"      value="{mydate->f:format.date(format:'Y')}" />
```

See  the PHP functions `date()` and `strftime()`(localized) for appropriate format strings.

Comment: And how can i use this to display my items per month / year?
```<f:variable name="day" value="{item.crdate->f:format.date(format:'d')}"/>```
```<f:groupedFor each="{items}" as="dayMonthYearOfDatetime" groupBy="day" groupKey="datum">```
does not work

Comment: I think you are in the false layer if you want to sort/filter your data in the view. That has to be done in the data request (repository). you may add a new function in your repository `getDataGroupedByMonth(`...)` which can be called in your controller to provide appropriate FLUID variables.

Comment: Thats why is tought i had to use a viewhelper but i dont know what i have to write

Comment: that's another subject, unrelated to this question so I don't write it in detail in my answer. open a new question with the topic how you can filter/ sort/ group your data for fluid output. in short: in your controller you might find a call to the function `findAll()` which needs to get a pendant `findSortedByGroup()` or similar, where you build your special query.